# how to setup python app with pyinstaller which will work without internet connection

Tags: pyinstaller, python-3.9

I created an executed version using pyinstaller, but on a computer without internet access the  app is not working correctly. Only index.html is loaded, and analisys not work https://github.com/evrycollin/py-sentiment-api-server How can I prepare this app ^^ for working on PC without internet connection?